# How can I run each junit test as if running newly every time?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

In Junit, I have 2 tests. If I run individually, it is taking 4sec each. But if I run together also it is taking 4-5sec. I expected 8secs.

In both the tests, only input varies.

It is not spring project. It is not using databases.

It uses Aspose word to create MS-Word from xml.

How can I run each test as if running newly every time.?

Comment: at least post your 2 tests so we can take a look at it.

Comment: So you want your tests to be slow? Why?

Comment: One reason could be JVM startup and class loading times: if run separately the JVM starts twice and has to load all classes twice

Comment: Are the 2 tests influencing each other? or why would you not want them to run that fast

Comment: I am checking one performance issue. So I like to calculate the time taken to produce 70 documents. Because of this caching, I could not get the correct execution time.

I cannot post my test case logic.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that JIT compiler in java is doing optimization when a method is running frequently. This is the reason for the performance improvement.